# How to finds if two entities are in the same group in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follwos:

```
       City     Name
0   Seattle    Alice
1   Seattle      Bob
2  Portland  Mallory       
3  Portland      Bob
```

Given two names I want to find whether they are in the same or not.
What is an efficient way to do this?
I was thinking about group by "City", but I don't know how to check if two names are in the same group.

(the dataframe I'm using is much larger with millions of rows and I want to find  two or more people in the same city multiple times)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
names = ['Alice', 'Bob']
df[df.Name.isin(names)].groupby('City').Name.nunique() > 1
```

yields

```
City
Portland    False
Seattle      True
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```

Enclose with `(..).any()` to get a summary `True` / `False` result.

If one person can be several times in the same `City`, you could use `.drop_duplicates(['Name', 'City')` first.

Wrapped in a function:

```
def same_city(df, n1, n2):
    same = df[df.Name.isin(names)].groupby('City').Name.nunique() > 1
    return same, same.any()

result, summary = same_city(df, 'Alice', 'Bob')
```

yields:

```
City
Portland    False
Seattle      True
Name: Name, dtype: bool
True
```

Comment: thanks however I'm not looking for groups with more than 1 members.

Comment: given two names, e.g., Alice and Bob, I wan to see if they are in the same city or not.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to use `groupby`:

```
x = "Mallory"
y = "Alice"
any(any(names[1].str.contains(x)) and any(names[1].str.contains(y)) for names in df.groupby('City').Name)

# False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def bothInCity(df, n1, n2):
    s = {n1, n2}
    c = df.groupby('City').Name.apply(set)
    chk = lambda x: s.issubset(x)
    return c.loc[c.apply(chk)]
```

Then use it like:

```
bothInCity(df, 'Bob', 'Alice')

City
Seattle    {Bob, Alice}
Name: Name, dtype: object
```